# Braces from texttt are not intepreted as braces but as f and g

Tags: braces, typewriter

When I copy-paste curly brackets (aka *braces*) from `\texttt{}` mode, they are interpreted as *f* and *g*. What can I do to get proper curly brackets? I tried to use `\string` but this seems not to allow to be split across multple line

---

Here is my minimal working example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq}
\newcommand*\widefbox[1]{\fbox{\hspace{2em}#1\hspace{2em}}}

\begin{document}

Compiles but gives "f g"-problem:
\begin{empheq}[box=\fbox]{align*}
&\texttt{\{}\\
&\texttt{something}\\
&\texttt{\}} 
\end{empheq}

Compiles and gives proper curly brackets, but I need three lines not one:
\begin{empheq}[box=\fbox]{align*}
\texttt{\string{ something \string}}
\end{empheq}

\iffalse
Does not compile:
\begin{empheq}[box=\fbox]{align*}
\texttt{\string{ \\
 something \\
 \string}}
\end{empheq}
\fi

\end{document}
```

Comment: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqSD3.png) is what I get when I compile your code... no `f g`-problem.

Comment: The same as I do. And when I copy and paste from the generated pdf, they are correct.

Comment: Try adding `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, but I can't reproduce the issue. What TeX distribution and operating system are you running?

Comment: you want `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` so that `\{` uses the ascii `{` slot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't reproduce the issue; on the other hand, if you want to get the braces in the monospaced font you can either load

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

or input them as

```
\texttt{\symbol{`\{}}
```

and

```
\texttt{\symbol{`\}}}
```